# Resume last print job from command line

Tags: printing, cups, lpd

To resume a job from command line I can call `lpq` which gives me the job number for example 211 and then `lp -i 211 -H resume`.

However is there a way

- to resume the *last* job without figuring out its job id first
- to resume just all holded jobs with one command

Answer (score 1):

`cupsenable --release $print_queue` should push all held jobs out to the printer (assuming it's still accepting jobs).  If the job got held because the printer is marked offline, you may need to `cupsenable $print_queue` and `cupsaccept $print_queue`  (or in one step `lpadmin -E $print_queue`), also.